# How to resolve a "driver failure" error in the Cisco VPN client connecting from a Windows 7 client

Tags: windows-7, vpn

I have recently upgraded my laptop from Windows Vista SP1 to Windows 7 Professional.

After the upgrade, if I try to use the Cisco VPN client to connect to a network, I get this message:

```
Secure VPN Connection terminated locally by the Client.
Reason 440: Driver Failure.
```

Prior to the upgrade, I was able to connect with no problems.

The version of the client I am using is 5.0.05.0290.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**This is what worked for me:**

- Un-install the vpn client

*Reboot*

**(If Win-10 or higher, skip this next step)**

- Run this file: ftp://files.citrix.com/winfix.exe

*Reboot*

- If 32-bit: Run this file: ftp://files.citrix.com/dneupdate.msi
- If 64-bit: Run this file: ftp://files.citrix.com/dneupdate64.msi

*Reboot*

- Install the VPN client again

*Reboot*

[Instructions taken from here.](http://weblogs.asp.net/bhouse/archive/2009/01/15/how-to-successfully-install-cisco-vpn-client-on-windows-7.aspx)

Comment: These steps also work with Windows 8.1 Professional and Cisco Systems VPN Client Version 5.0.07.0440.

Comment: For Windows 10 you do not need to run winfix or uninstall Cisco VPN Client, just run 32 bit or 64 bit dneupdate and Cisco VPN Client should work

Comment: Thanks Brian, I've incorporated that advice into the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Forget the Cisco client.  Use Shrew Soft.  All the way up to windows 7 64-bit clients.  Cisco doesn't offer and to my knowledge isn't planning a 64-bit client.

http://shrew.net/

(Works with Cisco VPN - that is, I'm not suggesting that you replace the Cisco router)

Comment: They are pushing the AnyConnect SSL Vpn client. I have it running just fine on my Win7 x64 install at work.

Comment: But it isn't free, is it?

Comment: SSL VPN licenses are not free.  I believe they were at one point but it is no longer the case.

Comment: Yes, but this is a question about the client, not the server.  Only the server normally uses a CA-signed ssl cert

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall the Cisco client and reinstall.  It'll work fine after the re-install.

Comment: This did not work.

Comment: Really?  Both my machines which were upgraded from Vista to Beta, to RC, to RTM just needed an uninstall and reinstall at each upgrade to work correctly.  I'm running the same version 5.0.05.0290.  I assumed that would work.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

DO NOT UNINSTALL AND REINSTALL - DOES NOT WORK

I have seen so many people go through this ridiculous process of uninstalling and Reinstalling the VPN Client. Follow these and your life will be made a lot easier.

Description
During the install or upgrade process, the uninstaller is not able to remove the old Cisco VPn LAN and thus creates a new one.

Solution 1.
1. Goto Start --> Settings --> Network Connections --> View Network Connections
2. On the listed Connections, you will fine two Cisco Local Area Connections. The first will have a **disabled** Status, the second one will have a **connected** status. 
3. Select the Cisco VPN LAN connection that has a connected status and disable it by right clicking and select **disable**
4. That is all you need to do

Solution 2.
1. Open Device Manager
2. Select Network Adapters
3. Uninstall the Cisco Adapter without the Disabled Icon (Red Top Left icon)
4 Thats it

Now as a side note, there also instances where you do not have any Local Area connections in your Network Connections for Cisco. To correct this, locate the msi file, and right click on it and run a repair. This will create a new VPN Local Area Connection Entry.
Thanks for allowing me share this with you

Answer (score 0):

Better still, just went to Control Panel/Programs & set to repair install....BINGO!!!! worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Just to add my experience to the list: I had this exact same problem. I read the various answers here and tried the suggestions for avoiding an install/reinstall. None of them worked for me. I did the uninstall / reinstall, and now I am back in business.

Answer (score 0):

control panel / repair worked. Make sure to go to restart the Cisco service cause it will be stopped. does not require restart.