# WIndows 8.1 VPn stops working

Tags: sonicwall, cisco-vpn, l2tp, windows-8.1

I am having a problem that every day i have to re-install my cisco VPN client because it will not work. I can connect and the routes get published to by computer, but i can not ping anything on the remote network.

This issue also affects my Windows L2TP vpn. Its issue is that it will not connect. I have looked in the Symantec Endpoint Protection and do not see any of the traffic being blocked.

It seems like everything but wireless and Lan networking gets hosed.

Is anyone else having this issue? Could really use some help.

Have also had the same results with the Sonicwall SSL vpn. Once one stopped working they all stop

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after my Win8 installation and after upgrade to Win 8.1 once more. Solution is to apply some patches prepared by Citrix company.

Try to use [this procedure](https://serverfault.com/questions/61418/how-to-resolve-a-driver-failure-error-in-the-cisco-vpn-client-connecting-from/86284#86284) written by [JosephStyons](https://serverfault.com/users/1553/josephstyons). Be patient and do all requested steps and reboots.